# How to build some targets with C++14 and some with C++17 by using cmake?

Tags: build, cmake, c++17

I am using cmake to build my C++ project. In my top `CMakesList.txt` file I have these directives:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++-8)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

I am interested in using C++17 for my project. However one of my 3rd party libraries does not compile with C++17 due to dynamic exceptions. Is it possible to only compile one target with C++14 and the rest with C++17 in cmake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` is just a default value for [CXX_STANDARD](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/prop_tgt/CXX_STANDARD.html) target's property. You may assign this property in a different manner for different targets:

```
set_target_properties(<target1> PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 14)
set_target_properties(<target2> PROPERTIES CXX_STANDARD 17)
```